# Помощь в написании консольного меню С#

Tags: c#, консоль, menu

В моем проекте реализовано интерактивное консольное меню, но мне нужно немного переписать класс, чтобы реализация была правильнее.
Прошу подсказку, либо идею как это сделать.

Это класс меню:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public string Text;
    public int Id;
}
```

Создание меню:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int OutPutListPeople = 0;
            const int OutPutListTimeline = 1;
            const int Exit = 2;

            List<MenuItem> mainMenu = new List<MenuItem>
            {
                new MenuItem{Id =OutPutListPeople, Text = "Вывести список людей"},
                new MenuItem{Id =OutPutListTimeline, Text = "Вывести список событий"},
                new MenuItem{Id = Exit, Text = "Выход"},
            };
```

И сам код, осуществляющий по меню передвижение:

```
while (true)
            {
                DrawMenu(mainMenu,index, "Главное меню \n");
                switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                        if (index < mainMenu.Count - 1)
                            index++;
                        else
                            index = 0;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                        if (index > 0)
                            index--;
                        else
                            index = mainMenu.Count - 1;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                        switch (mainMenu[index].Id)
                        { 
                            case OutPutListPeople:
                                PrintLogic.PrintPeopleList(DataReader.readedPeople);
                                ReturnToMainMenu(mainMenu, index);
                                break;
                            case OutPutListTimeline:
                                PrintLogic.PrintTimelineList(DataReader.readedTimeline);
                                ReturnToMainMenu(mainMenu, index);
                                break;
                            case Exit:
                                Console.WriteLine("Перед выходом выберите как сохранить изменения, если это нужно");
                                ExitMenu.ExecuteExitMenu(DataReader.readedPeople,DataReader.readedTimeline,ExitMenu.exitMenu);
                                ReturnToMainMenu(mainMenu, index);
                                return;
                        }
                        break;
                }
```

C начала был вид `case 0 case 1 и т.д`, сейчас, как вы можете заметить, я заменил все на константы, но таких меню несколько, пунктов больше и получается много констант, мне кажется, что это не самый правильный и визуально не самый приятный способ, но другой не могу придумать, кроме как еще вместо чисел использовать `string` с названиями.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133560/discussion-on-question-by-ilya-kvashnin------).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я вам несколько раз говорил, используйте ООП, но что-то как-то у вас не задалось.

Движок отрисовки менюшки как технология - это одно, а организовать так, чтобы не умереть при дальнейшей разработке - нужен навык. Нельзя все время жить на чужом коде, надо изучать, как оно на самом деле работает.

Начнем с объектной модели самого меню. Что общего у всех пунктов меню? Название.

```
public abstract class MenuItem
{
    public string Name { get; }

    public MenuItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Пусть будет название.

Далее, что меню должно уметь:

- Открывать подменюшки
- Выполнять команды
- Закрывать подменюшки и переходить обратно в предыдущее меню

Так и поступим

```
public class MenuCategory : MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem[] Items { get; }

    public MenuCategory(string name, MenuItem[] items) : base(name)
    {
        Items = items;
    }
}

public class MenuAction : MenuItem
{
    public Action<MenuItem> Action { get; }

    public MenuAction(string name, Action<MenuItem> action) : base(name)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}

public class MenuBack : MenuItem
{
    public MenuBack(string name = "Назад") : base(name) { }
}
```

Здесь самое интересное - это делегат `public Action<IMenuItem> Action`. Я ему для удобства дал возможность принимать в аргументы пункт меню, и буду туда передавать ссылку на сам пункт меню, который был вызван, но вы можете вообще этот аргумент `IMenuItem` убрать, если не надо, или заменить на то что нужно.

Модель готова, теперь движок. Возьму уже ранее написанный код и немного переделаю.

```
public class Menu
{
    private MenuCategory _current;

    public Menu(MenuCategory root)
    {
        _current = root;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Stack<MenuCategory> wayBack = new Stack<MenuCategory>();
        int index = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            DrawMenu(0, 0, index);
            switch (Console.ReadKey(true).Key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                    if (index < _current.Items.Length - 1)
                        index++;
                    else
                        index = 0;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                    if (index > 0)
                        index--;
                    else
                        index = _current.Items.Length - 1;
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Enter:
                    switch (_current.Items[index])
                    {
                        case MenuCategory category:
                            wayBack.Push(_current);
                            index = 0;
                            _current = category;
                            Console.Clear();
                            break;
                        case MenuAction action:
                            action.Action(action);
                            break;
                        case MenuBack:
                            if (wayBack.Count == 0)
                                return;
                            MenuCategory parent = wayBack.Pop();
                            index = Array.IndexOf(parent.Items, _current);
                            _current = parent;
                            Console.Clear();
                            break;
                        default:
                            throw new InvalidCastException("Неизвестный тип пункта меню");
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DrawMenu(int row, int col, int index)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(col, row);
        Console.WriteLine(_current.Name);
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < _current.Items.Length; i++)
        {
            if (i == index)
            {
                Console.BackgroundColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
            }
            Console.WriteLine(_current.Items[i].Name);
            Console.ResetColor();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Из нововведений - это появился стек, который хранит в себе путь назад. И `switch` теперь не на номер пункта меню реагирует а на тип самого этого пункта. Другими словами, теперь количество веток в `switch` не зависит от количества пунктов меню. Вам ведь это надо было? И никаких рекурсий.

Теперь давайте соберем эту менюшку и запустим.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MenuCategory main = new MenuCategory("Главное меню", new MenuItem[]
    { 
        new MenuAction("Пункт 1", SomeActionMethod), 
        new MenuAction("Пункт 2", SomeActionMethod), 
        new MenuAction("Пункт 3", SomeActionMethod),
        new MenuCategory("Подменю 1", new MenuItem[]
        {
            new MenuAction("Пункт 1.1", SomeActionMethod),
            new MenuAction("Пункт 1.2", SomeActionMethod),
            new MenuAction("Пункт 1.3", SomeActionMethod),
            new MenuBack()
        }),
        new MenuCategory("Подменю 2", new MenuItem[]
        {
            new MenuAction("Пункт 2.1", SomeActionMethod),
            new MenuAction("Пункт 2.2", SomeActionMethod),
            new MenuBack()
        }),
        new MenuBack("Выход")
    });

    Menu menu = new Menu(main);
    menu.Run();

    Console.WriteLine("Выход из приложения, нажмите любую клавишу...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static void SomeActionMethod(MenuItem menuItem)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Вы нажали: {menuItem.Name}");
}
```

Вот и весь код.

Обратите внимание, насколько прост процесс сборки меню. Это и есть преимущества ООП. В качестве делегата я всем экшн-пунктам передаю один и тот же метод `SomeActionMethod`. Но можно разные, из разных классов, откуда угодно. За счет этого и получится, что разные пункты мею выполняют разные задачи.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вообще я изначально просто не хотел полностью менять структуру, то есть то, что вы написали на ООП, потому что я пока только понимаю, что вы написали, но сам пока так не практиковался. Поэтому там и написал выше, остановлюсь пока на `enum`, но понял, что переписывать потом нужно будет точно намного больше

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin если ответ был полезен, вы знаете что делать. :) Поиграйтесь хотя-бы с этим решением, создайте проект.

Comment: Да, галочку я поставил и стрелочку эту нажал, спасибо вам большое, перепишу структуру значит еще раньше без промежуточных `enum`ов, с ООП у меня только начинается знакомство, поэтому я все еще его побаиваюсь, но мы изучили его в теории перед сессией

Comment: Буду разбираться, я очень рад, потому что в душе, я все-таки не хотел прибегать к `enum` потому что что-то мне и подсказывало, что ООП здесь решит все проблемы и сделает это очень красиво

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin именно так, успехов!

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin переделал интерфейс на абстрактный класс, теперь ООП наследование выглядит более явно. Но суть не поменялась.

Comment: А как передавать методы, если когда я передаю например  `PrintLogic.PrintDeltaTimeline(DataReader.readedTimeline)` получаю ошибку `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'void' to 'System.Action<TimeTrees.MenuItem>'`

Comment: Также мне нужна в подменю функция, в котором я должен буду вручную писать данные, которые будут заменяться в файле, а я все время нахожусь в меню получается, какой должен быть метод, чтобы что-то написать вручную, а потом вернуться обратно в подменю

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin сигнатура метода неверная, видимо. Аргументы надо правильно указать. `SomeActionMethod` это пример метода, назовите как угодно и что угодно делайте внутри.

Comment: У вас вот в методе `SomeActionMethod` передается `MenuItem menuItem` что-то еще кроме этого я не могу передать, возникает вот выше указанная ошибка

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin создайте класс по аналогии `MenuAction`, укажите там любой тип, хоть несколько. Добавьте для него `case`. Вы же видите, как сделано. Никто вам не запрещает добавить еще классов.

Comment: Плохо понимаю, указать "там" тип это где?

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос сошлитесь на этот ответ.

Comment: А сослаться как правильнее? Просто что не понимаю, то и спросить?

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin Сослаться? Ссылкой наверное. Есть кнопка "Поделиться". Как умеете, так и спрашивайте.

Comment: А какая вам информация нужна в вопросе? Вопрос в том, как передавать методы с разными аргументами, я прикрепил что я хочу получить еще на выводе, там не должно быть меню, немного не понимаю как на время из него выходить, что нужно еще?

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin когда вы задаете вопрос, вы информацию не мне сообщаете, а всем, кто его будет читать. Я может отвечу на него, а может кто-то другой ответит.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1380344/461490 попытался описать, не знаю насколько понятно, буду ждать, может кто и поймет меня