# Как расширить класс, чтобы можно было передавать методы с разными аргументами

Tags: c#, консоль

Переписав на код из этого ответа на мой вопрос: [Помощь в написании консольного меню С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1375641/461490)
В нем и находится весь код класса.

Я не понимаю как использовать методы с разными аргументами

Создаем меню:

```
    {
        new MenuAction("Пункт 1", //метод),
        new MenuCategory("Подменю 1", new MenuItem[]
        {
            new MenuAction("Пункт 1.1", //метод),
            new MenuBack()
        }),
        new MenuBack("Выход")
    });

Menu menu = new Menu(main);
            menu.Run();
```

Допустим, что я хочу, чтобы пункт первый выводил все события, должно выглядеть вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также тут я не до конца понимаю как выходить на время из меню, так как я это решал в предыдущей версии меню рекурсией, но это если вдруг будет попутно, для начала как все-таки реализовывать методы хотелось бы понять.
Это один из самых простых пунктов меню, но дальше, надеюсь станет понятнее и справлюсь сам.

Так выглядит метод, который выводит это само меню

```
public static class PrintLogic
    {
        public static void PrintTimelineList(List<TimelineEvent> events)
        {
            ConsoleHelper.ClearScreen();
            "Список событий".Center();

            foreach (TimelineEvent line in events)
            {
                string idParticipant = String.Empty;
                if (line.IdParticipant != null)
                {
                    foreach (int id in line.IdParticipant)
                    {
                        idParticipant = idParticipant + $"{id} ";

                    }
                    Console.WriteLine($"{line.DateEvent.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} \t" +
                        $"{line.Description}" +
                        $"\nId людей, которые учавстсовали в этом событии: "
                        + idParticipant);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{line.DateEvent.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")} \t" +
                        $"{line.Description} \t");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Ему нужно передавать в виде аргумента `List<TimelineEvent> events`, где структура класса `TimelineEvent`:

```
public class TimelineEvent
    {
        public DateTime DateEvent { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<int> IdParticipant { get; set; }
    }
```

Считываются данные все с файла и обычно передаю `DataReader.readedTimeline`.

Если что-то еще нужно, дополню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Берем вот этот класс из ответа

```
public class MenuAction : MenuItem
{
    public Action<MenuItem> Action { get; }

    public MenuAction(string name, Action<MenuItem> action) : base(name)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

И переписываем вот так

```
public class MenuPrintAction : MenuItem
{
    public Action<List<TimelineEvent>> Action { get; }

    public MenuPrintAction(string name, Action<List<TimelineEvent>> action) : base(name)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Заносим в дерево менюшек

```
new MenuPrintAction("Пункт 1", PrintLogic.PrintTimelineList),
```

Полдела сделано, теперь вызвать надо это как-то

```
case MenuPrintAction printAction:
    printAction.Action(/*сюда вставить ваш список*/);
    break;
```

Как именно список станет доступен из метода `Run` - вам решать.

---

Вы можете этот список даже в самом классе `MenuPrintAction` хранить, например так.

```
public class MenuPrintAction : MenuItem
{
    public Action<List<TimelineEvent>> Action { get; }
    public List<TimelineEvent> TimelineEvents { get; }

    public MenuPrintAction(string name, Action<List<TimelineEvent>> action, List<TimelineEvent> timelineEvents) : base(name)
    {
        Action = action;
        TimeLlineEvents = timelineEvents;
    }
}
```

```
new MenuPrintAction("Пункт 1", PrintLogic.PrintTimelineList, list),
```

```
printAction.Action(printAction.TimelineEvents);
```

Решать вам, как оно должно работать

---

Как прикрутить к меню свою програмную логику.

Создайте класс, например такой

```
public class MyApplication
{
    // здесь какие-то данные
    private int i;

    // здесь какие-то методы
    public void Increment()
    {
        i++;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

Можно создать такой пункт

```
public class MenuApplication : MenuItem
{
    public Action Action { get; }

    public MenuApplication(string name, Action action) : base(name)
    {
        Action = action;
    }
}
```

Добавить `case`

```
case MenuApplication appAction:
    appAction.Action();
    break;
```

Создать экземпляр вот так

```
var app = new MyApplication();

// здесь создание дерева меню
```

Добавить в дерево

```
new MenuApplication("Добавить +1", app.Increment),
new MenuApplication("Напечатать", app.Print),
```

Так понятнее?

Comment: А что вы имеете в виду под `Как именно список станет доступен из метода Run - вам решать.`
Я просто ловлю `NullReferenceException`, возможно вас неправильно понял

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin вы где-то список этот создаете, верно? Вот и передайте его в нужное место. Постарайтесь вникнуть, как это меню работает. А пока вы просто скопировали чужой код и не разобрались. Разберитесь.

Comment: Я понял, у меня файл не как раз таки не создавался, потому что это происходит в старом меню

Comment: Ну буду переписывать пытаться всю структуру, не понимаю пока только как мне вот то, о чем я писал, временно выходить из меню, чтобы у меня была возможность как на скриншоте вернуться назад, но возможно это будет через `MenuBack` теперь, такое есть предположение

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin временный выход из меню - это временный вход в метод, который вы из него вызвали. Возврат из этого метода вернет управление в меню, все наоборот. Меню снаружи, а ваша логика внутри него, понимаете? Заведите отдельный класс для логики, создайте его экземпляр, положите его как поле в Menu классе. И при вызове пунктов меню вызывайте из него что хотите, в нем же могут и все данные лежать. Под winforms писали? Вот похожая система, там форма передает вашим методам управление когда вы в ней что-то нажали, здесь то же самое.

Comment: Нет, winforms я еще, конечно, не трогал

Comment: Ну с начала я начну переводить всё меню на новый вид, если не получится реализовать, что вы описали, попробую спросить преподавателя или задам вопрос сюда, там уже и разберусь лучше с кодом, я поэтому ООП и опасался, вроде понимаю что к чему, но все-таки где-то не до конца и довольно сильно

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin дополнил ответ. Вытащите все свои рабочие методы в отдельный класс. Так будет проще разрабатывать приложение дальше.

Comment: Да, конечно, структуру я изменю, спасибо большое, буду разбираться и избавляться от старого меню

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin про делегаты читали? `Action` - делегат. Почитайте про них, добавит понимания. Заодно и преподу что-нибудь умного расскажете.

Comment: Да, с делегатами была другая ситуация, там еще и с `Linq` связанное, он и говорил пока не трогать, пойти другим способом, попроще