# Взаимосвязь между несколькими comboBox и массивами

Tags: c#, массивы, winforms, combobox

Имеются:

- Форма, на ней 3 ComboBox - comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3;
- 3 многомерных string массивов - s1, s2, s3.

Задача, привязать массивы к ComboBox, так чтобы от выбора в comboBox1 из доступных значений добавленных с массива s1 - в comboBox2 добавились значения с массива s2, но привязанные именно к тому пункту, который выбран в comboBox1, а от выбора уже в comboBox2 в comboBox3 добавились значения из s3 также привязанные значениям в comboBox2.

```
    String[] s1 = new String[] { "Архитектура", "Конструктив", "Сети", "Общего назначения" };
    String[][] s2 = new String[][]
       {
        new String[] {"Двери", "Окна", "Витражи", "Стена", "Пол"},
        new String[] {"Балка", "Колонна", "Стена", "Фундамент", "Арматура"},
        new String[] {"Воздуховод", "Соединительные детали", "Арматура воздуховода", "Механическое оборудование", "Соединительные детали трубопровода", "Гибкий трубопровод", "Сантихнический прибор", "Сплинкер", "Провод", "Кабельный лоток", "Короб", "Соединительные детали кабельного лотка", "Соединительные детали короба", "Электрооборудование", "Электроприборы", "Осветительный прибор"  },
        new String[] {"Аннотационные обозначения" }
       };

    String[][] s3 = new String[][]
      {
          //Архитектурные элементы
        new String[] {"Дверь одностворчатая", "Дверь двустворчатая"},
        new String[] {"Окно однополое", "Окно двуполое"},
        new String[] {"Витраж" },
        new String[] {"Стена гипсокартонная", "Стена кирпичная" },
        new String[] {"Пол типовой", "Пол с закладными" },
          //Конструктивные элементы
        new String[] {"Балка металлическая Уголок", "Балка металлическая Швеллер", "Балка металлическая Двутавр", "Балка желозобетонная Прямоугольная", "Балка желозобетонная Тавровая", "Балка желозобетонная Двутавровая", "Балка желозобетонная Трапециевидная" },
        new String[] {"Колонна металлическая ", "Колонна металлическая " },
        new String[] {"Стена базовая", "Стена фундамент" },
        new String[] {"Фундамент плита", "Фундамент ленточный", "Фундамент столбчатый" },
        new String[] {"Форма арматурного стержня" },
          //Элементы сетей
        new String[] {"Воздуховод1", "Воздуховод2", "Воздуховод3" },
        new String[] { "Соединительные детали1", "Соединительные детали2","Соединительные детали3" },
        new String[] {"Арматура воздуховода1", "Арматура воздуховода2", "Арматура воздуховода3"},
        new String[] {"Механическое оборудование1", "Механическое оборудование2", "Механическое оборудование3" },
        new String[] {"Соединительные детали трубопровода1", "Соединительные детали трубопровода2", "Соединительные детали трубопровода3"},
        new String[] {"Гибкий трубопровод1", "Гибкий трубопровод2", "Гибкий трубопровод3"},
        new String[] {"Сантихнический прибор1", "Сантихнический прибор2", "Сантихнический прибор3"},
        new String[] {"Сплинкер1", "Сплинкер2", "Сплинкер3"},
        new String[] {"Провод1", "Провод2", "Провод3"},
        new String[] {"Кабельный лоток1", "Кабельный лоток2", "Кабельный лоток3"},
        new String[] {"Короб1", "Короб2","Короб3"},
        new String[] {"Соединительные детали кабельного лотка1", "Соединительные детали кабельного лотка2", "Соединительные детали кабельного лотка3"},
        new String[] {"Соединительные детали короба1", "Соединительные детали короба2", "Соединительные детали короба3"},
        new String[] {"Электрооборудование1", "Электрооборудование2", "Электрооборудование3"},
        new String[] { "Осветительный прибор1", "Осветительный прибор2", "Осветительный прибор3" },
          //Элементы аннотаций
        new String[] {"Высотная отметка", "Заголовок разреза", "Заголовок Сетки", "Заголовок уровня", "Заголовок фрагмента", "Задняя часть разреза", "Марка двери", "Марка для нескольких материалам", "Марка зоны", "Марка изменения", "Марка изменения - Параллелограмм", "Марка ключевой пометки", "Марка лестниц", "Марка лестничного марша", "Марка лестничной опоры", "Марка лестничной площадки", "Марка материала", "Марка несущего каркаса", "Марка окна", "Марка помещения", "Марка фасада, основная часть_квадрат", "Марка фасада, основная часть_окружность", "Название вида", "Осевая линия", "Первый лист", "Первый лист - Текст", "Следущий лист - Текст", "Ссылка на вид", "Фиксированное направоение вверх" }
      };

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Заполнение Раздела
        comboBox1.Items.AddRange(s1);

        //Заполнение типа
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(s2);

        //Заполнение категории
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(s3);


    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
        comboBox2.Items.AddRange(s2[comboBox1.SelectedIndex]);

    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        comboBox3.Items.Clear();
        comboBox3.Items.AddRange(s3[comboBox2.SelectedIndex]);
        
    }
```

Ниже приложил скриншоты. Подскажите как сделать так, чтобы:

1. При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 1-го подмассива в массиве s2,  в comboBox3 попадали значения Архитектурных элементов с массива s3.
2. При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 2-го подмассива в массиве s2,  в comboBox3 попадали значения Конструктивных элементов с массива s3.
3. При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 3-го подмассива в массиве s2,  в comboBox3 попадали значения Элементов сетей с массива s3.
4. При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 4-го подмассива в массиве s2,  в comboBox3 попадали значения Элемелементов аннотаций с массива s3.

При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 1-го подмассива s2 - всё работает корректно
[image: При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 1-го подмассива s2 - всё работает корректно]

При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 2-го и далее подмассива s2 - выводит значения, как и для 1-го подмассива

[image: При выборе в comboBox2 значений из 2-го и далее подмассива s2 - выводит значения, как и для 1-го подмассива]

Но если выбрать элементы у которых индекс уходит за те значения, которых достигают 1-ый, 2-ой и 4-й подмассивы, то он хоть и неправильно, но всё же отображает, элементы из массива s3

[image: Но если выбрать элементы у которых индекс уходит за те значения, которых достигают 1-ый, 2-ой и 4-й подмассивы, то он хоть и неправильно, но всё же отображает, элементы из массива s3]

P.S. Понимаю, что необходимо сделать цикл с перебором в зависимости от индекса в `comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged`. Добавить условный оператор, в котором провести проверку на длину подмассива или некоего индекса, дойдя до которого, цикл закончит с одним подмассивом и перейдёт на следующий подмассив, но как реализовать не понимаю

Comment: Откуда начать: [Windows Forms Data Binding](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/windows-forms-data-binding?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). [Data Binding and Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/data-binding-and-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Ваши данные связаны отношениями Master/Detail: [How to](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/create-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8),  [Walkthrough](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/creating-a-master-detail-form-using-two-datagridviews?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: При использовании комбобоксов нужен [Lookup Table](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-create-a-lookup-table-with-the-windows-forms-bindingsource-component?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). Делать по аналогии, только без связи с БД. Главное, на что нужно обратить внимание - `BindingSource`.

Comment: Конечно, можно делать без привязки данных. Тогда обрабатывайте события комбобоксов. В обработчике события проверяете, какая строка выбрана и меняете данные в другом комбобоксе.

Comment: Чтобы изменить набор данных, будете код переписывать, или какой у вас план?

Comment: Всем спасибо, буду посмотреть

Comment: Я бы построил древовидную модель данных, на подобии [такой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1375879/373567), тогда чтобы заполнить следующий комбобокс, нужно будет только обратиться к выбранному элементу предыдущего, так как данные для заполнения будут прямо в нем.

Comment: @aepot
 Большое спасибо, очень похоже на то, что мне необходимо.