# Как вызвать метод из generic класса?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

У меня есть задача написать именной свой `stack` с помощью своего односвязного списка. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю как вызвать метод из дженерик класса в своем классе, отвечающем за создание пунктов в консольном меню.

Тут добавляется метод, который будет вызываться в консоли:

```
public class MainMenu
    {
        public static MenuCategory mainMenu = new MenuCategory("Main menu", new Menu[]
            {
                new MenuCategory("Stack",new Menu[]
                {
                    new MenuApplicationStackPush("Push",DynamicStructure.Core.Stack.Stack<T>.Push), //error
                    new ReturnMenu("Back")
                }),
                new ReturnMenu("Exit")
            });
    }
```

Вот так выглядит реализация класса, отвечающего за этот вызов:

```
public class MenuApplicationStackPush : Menu
    {
        public Action Action { get; }

        public MenuApplicationStackPush(string name, Action action) : base(name)
        {
            Action = action;
        }
    }
```

И вот сам `stack` и нужный мне метод `push`:

```
public class Stack<T> 
    {
        public static SinglyLinkedList<T> List = new SinglyLinkedList<T>();

        public static void Push()
        {
            var value = Console.ReadLine();
            List.InsertAtFront((T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)));
            Console.WriteLine($"Pushed {0}", value);
        }

    }
```

И на всякий случай приложу реализацию метода `InsertAtFront`

```
public void InsertAtFront(T item)
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (IsEmpty)
                    firstNode = lastNode = new ListNode<T>(item);
                else
                    firstNode = new ListNode<T>(item, firstNode);
                count++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://github.com/IlyaKvashnin/DynamicStructures/tree/stack
На всякий случай приложу ссылку на репозиторий

Comment: `У меня есть задача написать именной свой stack с помощью своего односвязного списка` ..... `классе, отвечающем за создание пунктов в консольном меню` wut?

Comment: опишите одну проблему, а то у вас в огороде бузина, а в Киеве дядька

Comment: `public static void Push()` Метод push в стеке существует только чтобы добаялть туда запись, переданную в метод как параметр. Что у вас происходит не имеет ничего общего с назначением метода и стеком вообще

Comment: Не используйте статику.

Comment: `List.InsertAtFront((T)Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(T)));` ну и вы что, думаете, что можно просто считать строку с консоли и таким волшебным образом её превратить в любой другой типа? Вот вам строка "vasya", сделайте из неё число =)

Comment: @tym32167 "Реализовать Стек с помощью списка." так звучит задание, поэтому приходится делать такой `push`

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin я тут не вижу связи. Стек сделать при помощи списка и городить статику и пустые пуши- абсолютно не связанные между собой вещи

Comment: @tym32167 реализовал как смог

Comment: Значит, у вас реализация стека неверная. Сначала реализуйте его надлежащим образом, потом уже думайте про меню

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать что-то из обобщения, надо дать ему конкретный тип.

Считайте, что например `Stack<int>` и `Stack<string>` это 2 разных класса, как если бы это были просто `StackInt` и `StackString`. А если компилятор не знает конкретного типа, то как он определит, метод какого именно типа класса вы хотите вызвать? Никак.

```
DynamicStructure.Core.Stack.Stack<int>.Push
```

Сам по себе стек - это тупо коллекция, он не должен ничего делать с данными, только складывать и отдавать.

```
public class Stack
{
    private SinglyLinkedList<string> list = new SinglyLinkedList<string>();

    public void Push(string value)
    {
        list.InsertAtFront(value);
    }
}
```

Всё, никакого мудрежа и никаких статичских членов. Бездумное использование статики - зло.

```
var stack = new Stack();
stack.Push("Hello world");
```

Или с обобщением

```
public class Stack<T>
{
    private SinglyLinkedList<T> list = new SinglyLinkedList<T>();

    public void Push(T value)
    {
        list.InsertAtFront(value);
    }
}
```

```
var stack = new Stack<string>();
stack.Push("Hello world");
```

---

Хотите пример простого стека на основе односвязного списка, вот, я сделяль.

```
public class Stack<T>
{
    private StackNode<T> tail;
    public int Count { get; private set; }

    public void Push(T value)
    {
        tail = new StackNode<T>(value, tail);
        Count++;
    }

    public T Pop()
    {
        if (tail == null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Стек пуст, нечего извлекать.");
        var node = tail;
        tail = tail.Previous;
        Count--;
        return node.Value;
    }
}

public class StackNode<T>
{
    public T Value { get; }
    public StackNode<T> Previous { get; }

    public StackNode(T value, StackNode<T> previous)
    {
        Value = value;
        Previous = previous;
    }
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
    stack.Push(1);
    stack.Push(2);
    stack.Push(3);

    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(stack.Pop());
    }
}
```

```
3
2
1
```

Кстати, о консольных менюшках я писал здесь: [Помощь в написании консольного меню С#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1375641/373567)

Comment: То есть вариантов вызвать Stack<T> у меня нет?

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin все что вы пишете на статике - уже одна большая ошибка. Поэтому сложно угадать, какой вам нужен результат. Обобщения созданы, чтобы не дублировать код для одинаковых логически классов, больше ни для чего. Для чего вам здесь обобщение - вообще непонятно.

Comment: Для операции push после единицы через запятую указывается значение помещаемого элемента `(это может быть число либо слово)`.

Comment: Во-первых для этого, хотелось бы как раз не дублировать и не думать число там или слово. Ну и по определению `List` работает с дженериками, поэтому тоже не хотелось привязываться к типу данных

Comment: А вы бы не могли показать правильную реализацию `Push` в моем случае без статики? Либо это уже другой вопрос, ну или требует много времени вашего?

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin если не хотите привязываться к типу данных, используйте хоть `object`, обобщение тут не при чем. Если же у вас ввод строк с клавы, что `string` может и числа хранить в виде текста и строки, верно?

Comment: Ну да, видимо стоит подумать что будет лучше `obejct`, либо же вызов как вы указали в ответе.

Comment: А я могу сделать так? DynamicStructure.Core.Stack.Stack<object>.Push

Comment: @aepot раз уж помогаете, сделайте хотя бы список непубличным и уберите статику, а то люди же смотрят 

Comment: @tym32167 сделал до того как прочитал этот коммент.

Comment: @aepot то то я удивился скорости реакции :)

Comment: Буду думать, спасибо вам

Comment: @IlyaKvashnin показал пример односвязного стека, вдруг пригодится.

Comment: @aepot Для консольного меню как раз я все еще использую ваш код)

Comment: @aepot Универ вернул меня к c#, поэтому приходится вспоминать, синтаксис и суть помню, а вот уже такие более глубокие вещи не помню)

Comment: @aepot Нужно будет уточнить у преподавателя, что имеется в виду под стеком на основе односвязного списка, потому что как говорили выше использовать прям `List` выглядит странным, но задание я понимаю именно так