# Не получается сделать проверку в цикле while

Tags: c#, while

Нужно чтобы вводились только цифры(с этим проблем нет) и плюс проверка на то, чтобы цифра не превышала значение 4.Но почему то проверка на значение  больше 4 игнорируется.

```
static int Set_Select()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите нужное действие: ");
        Console.WriteLine("1.Сложение\n2.Вычитание\n3.Умножение\n4.Деление");
        
        int select;
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        bool one_input = int.TryParse(input,out select);
        
    while(!one_input && select > 4)
    {       
        Console.WriteLine("Ошибка,попробуйте ещë раз");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        one_input = int.TryParse(input,out select);
        
         
    }
    return select;
    
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Парсинг числа проходит успешно, `!one_input` возващает `false`. Поэтому следующая проверка не производится.

Чтобы заработало, поменяйте немного условие `!one_input || select > 4`. Кстати, его можно улучшить `!one_input || select > 4 || select < 1`.

А чтобы не дублировать код, я бы написал так:

```
static int Menu()
{
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Выберите нужное действие:");
        Console.WriteLine("1.Сложение\n2.Вычитание\n3.Умножение\n4.Деление");
        
        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        if (int.TryParse(input, out int select) && select > 0 && select < 5)
        {
            return select;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Мне до вашего уровня пахать и пахать, рано мне ещё  прям в условиях проверки методы писатьТолько не понял с моментом || или, он же не обязывает чтоб оба условия были верные, главное чтоб что то одно было true, или я чуть не понял)

Comment: ой ей ей, додумался, вспомнил таблицу булевых операторов, если  false & & true то будет false, спасибо❤️

Comment: @gachi_muchenik пахать и пахать - это вот до [этого уровня](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1375879/373567), а условия писать просто. Вы же поняли код, значит он достаточно просто написан, верно?

Comment: Ну свой то код я понял,я ведь его и писал, просто упустил  из виду таблицу булевых операторов. В ооп пока не лезу,не хочу пока жизнь усложнять себе

Comment: @gachi_muchenik ООП упрощает жизнь, а не наоборот :) помните об этом, когда будете вникать. Если вдруг стало невероятно сложно, значит мысль пошла не туда, остановитесь и переизучите сначала.